# Commitment "Processed" vs "Confirmed" vs "Finalized"

Tags: transactions, web3.js, cluster

What's the difference between the different levels of commitment, 'Processed', 'Confirmed' and 'Finalized'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the [Solana docs for commitment definitions](https://docs.solanalabs.com/consensus/commitments):

| Property | Processed | Confirmed | Finalized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Received block | x | x | x |
| Block on majority fork | x | x | x |
| Block contains target transaction | x | x | x |
| 66%+ stake voted on block |  | x | x |
| 31+ confirmed blocks built atop block |  |  | x |

Comment: This is a good answer but adding a reference would make it even better!

Comment: Source is https://docs.solana.com/cluster/commitments FWIW

Comment: in fact, this is the original. it was added to the docs later, https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/27265