# confirmTransaction not waiting for createAccount to have been created

Tags: web3.js, commitment

There's definitely a gap in my understanding of how txs are processed by solana validators, or how accounts are created. I tried this on localnet and devnet, and running into same issue on both.

I wrote a program, and sending 2 ixs to it: first to create an account, and second to write data into that account. I know that I should be sending both ixs as part of a single txs, but for learning purposes I decided to try to send them separately.

I first create a `createAccount` tx:

```
const createEchoBufferAccountIx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: someSignerPayerPubkey,
    newAccountPubkey: someAccountPubkey,
    lamports: someRentFreeAmount,
    space: someSpace,
    programId
})
const createAccountTx = new Transaction().add(createEchoBufferAccountIx);
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createAccountTx, [someSignerPayerPubkey, someAccountPubkey], { commitment: "confirmed" });
```

and then send a tx to to write some data to the created Account. When doing so, I get the following error:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/samlaf/devel/solana/echo-program-bootcamp-tutorial/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4546:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/samlaf/devel/solana/echo-program-bootcamp-tutorial/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4505:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/samlaf/devel/solana/echo-program-bootcamp-tutorial/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4493:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/samlaf/devel/solana/echo-program-bootcamp-tutorial/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program LQ4Zfo3Ch7t6QkAc4AMB8CGbxf51CL4SSG9aGdewjFX invoke [1]',
    'Program LQ4Zfo3Ch7t6QkAc4AMB8CGbxf51CL4SSG9aGdewjFX consumed 8569 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program LQ4Zfo3Ch7t6QkAc4AMB8CGbxf51CL4SSG9aGdewjFX failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'
  ]
}
```

However, the **biggest puzzle** for me, is that if I remove the `commitment: "confirmed"` argument to sendAndConfirmTransaction, it actually waits for the first tx to have created the account. My config is

```
Config File: /Users/samlaf/.config/solana/cli/config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899 
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: /Users/samlaf/.config/solana/id.json 
Commitment: confirmed
```

I've think I've narrowed the problem down and it seems like either this `confirmTransaction` call (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/d7ed86a68c21238d8c66f9b1f9b3a7a2e9a92c8e/src/util/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts#L51) is not working, or my understanding of how accounts are created is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [connection.onAccountChange](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange) and have your `write data` transaction inside the callback. don't forget to use `'confirmed'` as commitment too.

Comment: That sounds like an ad-hoc workaround solution to me, unless I'm again misunderstanding something about solana internals of account creations. When are account changes emitted? Wouldn't they be emitted during the very same slot that the createAccount tx is processed?

Comment: have you tried using "finalized"?

Comment: I have and it works, but I don't understand why. Especially on a localnet, why would I need to wait for finalization for the account to be present?

Comment: in this case. This is what you're looking for https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/commitment-processed-vs-confirmed-vs-finalized

Comment: if this answers your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I know these definitions. Well actually I'd be interested in double checking:
- is there a difference between "processed" and "confirmed" on a localnet (since the single test-validator is the entire cluster.. I believe)?

Comment: But my problem is really a fundamentally bad behavior of the `confirmTransaction` function. Why does it work when I don't include the "confirmed" parameter (I'm guessing it uses the "confirmed" from my solana config file), but doesn't work when I do include the parameter (I'm guessing it does something wrong here...)

Answer (score 2):

The “Transaction simulation failed” part of that error message indicates that your second transaction failed *in preflight*. You have to make sure that your transaction is simulated at the level of commitment you expect it to succeed against.

Specify the simulation commitment level when you send the transaction:

```
await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  writeSomeDataToThatAccountWeJustCreatedTx,
  [someSignerPayerPubkey],
  {
    commitment: "confirmed",
    preflightCommitment: "confirmed",  // Add this.
  },
);
```