# can the order of blocks change going from confirmed -> finalized?

Tags: block

so I broadly understand the difference between what it means for something to be confirmed vs finalised (eg [Commitment "Processed" vs "Confirmed" vs "Finalized"](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/commitment-processed-vs-confirmed-vs-finalized))

but what I don't really understand is, how much can the order of blocks etc change as you go from one to the other?

For example, say I am requesting the content of block X and that is not yet  finalized (so fewer than 31 blocks after it), but is confirmed.  Is it common that if i then ask about block X later that it will either have different content, or that the order of blocks has changed in some way?