# lifetime of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, block

Would anyone be able to explain what happens to a transaction from the time it is submitted, to the time it ends up in a finalized block?

Once the transaction has been confirmed, has it already been put in a block? Or is the process of bundling transactions into blocks separate from the process of confirming transactions?

Many Thanks

Comment: check out the awesome table here: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/commitment-processed-vs-confirmed-vs-finalized/1761

Comment: Is there any difference between a transaction being confirmed and a block being confirmed?  E.g I can use the getSignaturesForAddress to ask for signatures of all confirmed transactions related to some program.  Those come with a slot, but does the fact that the transaction is confirmed imply that that block/slot is also confirmed?  Or can a transaction only be confirmed by definition when it is in a block that has itself been confirmed?