# Alchemy endpoint gives wrong wallet balance

Tags: typescript, mainnet, endpoint

I am doing unit tests and I notice that my alchemy endpoint lags behind mainnet-beta in several situations. Sometimes it doesn't get a websocket account update, but the worst obvious case is after doing a swap SOL/USDC: my sol balance has changed and the mainnet-beta endpoint captures that, but not the alchemy endpoint. Any explanation?

```
import {Connection, PublicKey} from "@solana/web3.js";

let connexion_mainnet = new Connection(
    "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com",
    "processed");
let connexion_alchemy = new Connection(
    "https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/my_end_point",
    "processed");

let wallet = new PublicKey("my_wallet_address")
let balance_mainnet = await connexion_mainnet.getBalance(wallet, "processed")
let balance_alchemy = await connexion_alchemy.getBalance(wallet, "processed")

// fail, balance_mainnet is the right SOL balance,
// according to solscan and orca UI
assert balance_mainnet === balance_achemy
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be, that you did your swap using another commitment level than the getBalance call? Usually you should go for at least "confirmed" instead of processed because then 66% of stake has voted for that block which makes sure that it will get finalized eventually. See here: [Commitment "Processed" vs "Confirmed" vs "Finalized"](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/commitment-processed-vs-confirmed-vs-finalized)

Beside that different RPCs nodes have different loads and feature sets. Could also be that the alchemy RPC was still catching up with the cluster maybe. Last time I tried alchemy didn't have accountSubscribe yet. If you can reproduce it probably best to write to the alchemy support.

Comment: I was the same commitment, processed. I don't think it has an impact here because I have waited like 5min after the swap to check the balance!

The catching from the RPC would be a reason, or maybe Alchemy is using a caching system with low frequency refresh

Comment: Check if both rpc are in the same block.