# What is commitment on Solana and why it is needed?

Tags: commitment

I am reading the solana docs, commitment, but it is little confusing, is there anyone who can explain in better way for good understanding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commitment "Processed" vs "Confirmed" vs "Finalized"](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1760/commitment-processed-vs-confirmed-vs-finalized)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Solana Commitment docs](https://docs.solanalabs.com/consensus/commitments):

> Commitment measures the network confirmation for the block.

In any distributed system, one has to specify the level of consensus between nodes that is required to consider something to have been 'accepted'. It's a tradeoff between responsiveness and certainty.

'Confirmed' is faster, but there's a small chance your commit ends up in a short-lived fork rather than in the main blockchain. 'Finalised' is slower, but provides greater certainty because more blocks have been built on top of the block containing your transaction, which means it is very likely your transaction is in the main blockchain.

See https://docs.solanalabs.com/consensus/commitments for a table of the different commitment levels and their meanings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @DreamNinja thanks but the best thing to do is upvote it, and if it helps you, mark it as the accepted answer.